# How can I load all data from SQlite database? (Ionic 3, Angular 5, Cordova)

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

How can I load all data stored in sqlite storage at a time?

I have several data objects with different keys and id values.

I want to load them all on a single list using *ngFor directive.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
<p> {{ item.about }} </p>
</div>
```

and here's my home ts file for that:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {

      this.storage.get(item);

  }
```

this code will not work obviously. I know how to get a single data object using this this get() method but I don't know how to load everything at a time.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: also i think you mean `this.storage.get('item')` not `this.storage.get(item)`

Comment: Is the answer not correct ? Are you looking for something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IonicNative Storage wrapper exposes a `forEach` method.

This method will return all the key: value pairs

```
this.storage.forEach((value, key, iterationNumber) => {
   // here you can do whatever you want to do with all the data.
});
```

Read more about it here: [Ionic Storage: forEach](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/#forEach)

Comment: is there anything else you are looking for? bcoz you accepted the naswer and then unaccepted.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution shortly. but I'm unsure how this will work yet due to complexity of project I'm working on.. let me try!